# escaping output in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, security

I'm developing a custom theme that will never be available for download using _s as starter theme.

Do I need to escape all output for some security concern? I don't mean variables, I mean plain text. see:
`<h1>Product Name<h1>` vs

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php esc_html_e( 'That page can&rsquo;t be found.', 'theme' ); ?></h1>
```

The second example is taken from the 404.php base page from _s.

My guess is that they escape this html to prevent any translation error/vulnerability. But my question is:

is `<h1> Product Name</h1>` not secure/vulnerable in any way?

Thanks!!

PD. I found answers related to escaping variables, but I'm not sure about plain text.

Comment: You only need to escape the `<>` characters, not others really. And definitely the `&` one. Others? I don't think so, although you should avoid UTF-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your static HTML is static, unchanging, and it's valid as is, then **no**, there's no point in escaping it. The only thing you need is syntactically valid HTML which expresses what you want. If your HTML is not *dynamically* generated, you can ensure that it fulfils those criteria yourself by hand while writing it.

Having said that, [`esc_html_e`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_e) *translates* text into other languages, so has additional uses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, I will be the only one using this theme so I don't need to care about translations. I just wanted to make sure I was not missing any way the code was left unsecured, even if I didn't thought so. Better ask when you're a newbie.